# Random mysql crash when closing a statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
Statement statement =createStatement();
try (java.sql.ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery()) {
    while (resultset.next()) {
        myObject.setProcessingDate(resultset.getDate(1));
        myObject.set...

    }
}finally {
    if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

I know that statement object should be created in the try-with-resource block but this is a generated code.

Randomly, I'm getting the following exception:

```
caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@9h6d41205 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. 
Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.realClose(ServerPreparedStatement.java:549)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.close(ServerPreparedStatement.java:284)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.close(ProxyStatement.java:76)
    at mypackage.NamedParameterStatement.close(NamedParameterStatement.java:520)
```

I have googled but didn't find an explanation why I'm getting this crash when closing my statement.

The "auto" close of my resultset object should be called before entering into the finally block and than before my `statement.close()` got called.

Even if my `resultset.close()` is not called, I would expect `statement.close()` will also check if resultset is opened and close it if needed.

Am I missing something or why is this issue?

Comment: Which line of that stack trace implicates which line of the code presented?  My first impression from the code and the exception message is that the code in the question is at best peripherally related to the exception, and in particular, that if there is an association at all, then it is with *creating* or *executing* the statement, not with closing it.

Comment: *I have the following code:* Really - what query is it executing exactly?

Comment: The code is crashing when calling mypackage.NamedParameterStatement.close method which will simply close the prepared statement.
The first query is a select query

Comment: I still mistrust `createStatement`

Answer (score 2):

[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is as an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it

In fact, it has been automatically closed, you don't need to manually call the close method.

back to your question！

Pay attention to the error message you provided

> caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@9h6d41205 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection.

[refer here](https://support.datavirtuality.com/hc/en-us/articles/212166126-Error-message-Streaming-result-set-com-mysql-jdbc-RowDataDynamic-XXXXXX-is-still-active-)

> streaming mode has one limitation: When a resultset is open in streaming mode on a MySQL connection, you cannot use that same database connection to run other queries.

In other words, when you execute this statement, it is likely that there are already other result sets in the open stage.

Answer (score 0):

> I have googled but didn't find an explanation why I'm getting this crash when closing my statement.

I'm not sure you are.  Not when *closing* the statement.

> The "auto" close of my resultset object should be called before entering into the finally block and than before my statement.close got called.

Quite so.

> Even if my resultset.close is not called, I would expect statement.close() will also check if resultset is opened and close it if needed.

The specs say that `Statement.close()` has that effect, yes.

Read the exception message again, especially the highlighted part:

> Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@9h6d41205 is still active. **No statements may be issued** when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection.

That message sure doesn't look like it's about closing the statement. And per your own analysis, it should not be about a conflict between closing the `Statement` and `ResultSet` that are created by the same execution of that code fragment.

I'm inclined to think that you have a *different* `ResultSet` associated with a *different* `Statement` belonging to the same `Connection` still active, and that the exception is thrown when you try to create or execute a new `Statement`, not when you try to close a statement (though the analysis is not much affected if the exception is thrown from the `close()` after all).

Good candidates for the source of such an issue include

- having erroneously failed to close a previously obtained `ResultSet`;
- using the same `Connection` concurrently in multiple threads; or
- simply using your connection to attempt to perform a new query within the context of processing the results of another query.

The last of those should be determinate, so identifiable from the full stack trace.  The other two are more likely to seem random, and you might well expect to see similar exceptions originating from different parts of your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Answered your own question.

Hence, it is good practice to explicitly close the `Statement`.

True, it must be added here that if an implicit closure is performed, i.e.  if [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is used, then the exception that occurs when executing `close()` should be caught separately.

The `AutoClosable` interface **does not** automatically close a `Statement`, but is used to close it *implicitly*, as in the situation mentioned above.

And now

//todo and if it was not possible to close the statement, then what to do?

Well, here the reasons may be different, but in most cases there is little sense from this, so the exception can simply be ignored.

> I know that statement object should be created in the try-with-resource block but this is a generated code.

Here is a typical code for working with a database

```
 try(Connection con = .......) {
   ......
   try (Statement stmt = con.PrepareStatement(...)) {
     ......
     try(ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) {
       .........
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is also interesting is that the query is crashing randomly after more than two hours.
I rerun the same process/query and it work in less than one minute sometime the second retry, third retry...

This how the thread dump look when the query is stuck/running for long time:

```
"f2297067-13d5-427a-83ec-fc31253922c6_Worker-6" #83 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=202433.86ms elapsed=85008.80s tid=0x00007fb527394800 nid=0x159 runnable  [0x00007fb462df1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.19/Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.19/Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.19/Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.19/Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
    - locked <0x00007fba710040e8> (a com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.19/Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readMessageLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:137)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readMessage(SimplePacketReader.java:102)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readMessage(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readMessage(MultiPacketReader.java:66)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readMessage(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ResultsetRowReader.read(ResultsetRowReader.java:75)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ResultsetRowReader.read(ResultsetRowReader.java:42)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1587)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming.next(ResultsetRowsStreaming.java:194)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming.next(ResultsetRowsStreaming.java:62)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1813)
    - locked <0x00007fba71004690> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
```